# How to make menu, navbar nav-pills nav-stacked collapse Twitter-bootstrap 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code, I want to make this menu collapse for mobile-devices

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="nav-menu">
        <li class="active" ><a href="index.php">Domov</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Koncerty</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakty</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Troll</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

And I want to do this:

[image: Collapsed nav example]

Comment: Are you not using the responsive css file in bootstrap? Add the missing file.

Comment: Im using, check new bootstrap. Bootstrap 3 doesn't have bootstrap.responsive.css . All of code is in bootstrap.css http://getbootstrap.com/ - download compiled files. and checks Bootstra/dist/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a similar question, which seems to have a detailed answer that will be useful for you. It didn't work perfectly for me, but it does seem much closer than I was before.

Check it out: [makes nav-pills collapsable just like nav-bar in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109704/makes-nav-pills-collapsable-just-like-nav-bar-in-bootstrap?rq=1)

Answer (score -5):

Try the following code. This should help you. I assume what you need from the reference link you provided. Though that site I guess is not using bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

You should get more help from docs

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: This doesn't show anything related to nav-pills. Read the question.