# Bootstrap Navbar troubleshooting: unexpected drop down menu behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation, navbar, pseudo-class

I'm having a few issues here, but the main issue is mobile responsiveness with drop down menus. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div><!--nav-header-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Practice <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--collapse-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div><!--navbar-->
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.navbar {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4f3838;}
.navbar .nav-pills li {
  font-size: 1.2em !important;}
.navbar .nav-pills a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 3px 0 3px;}
.navbar .nav-pills a:hover {
  color: black;}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background: black;}
```

I'm having two problems on mobile: first, after I click and then unclick the menu button it stays selected (it appears grey instead of black after it's been clicked), and then the main drop down menu displays horizontally, and the drop down within the drop down displays vertically creating a hot mess. I don't know what I've done to cause this or how to fix it. When I look at tutorials the example navbars are essentially the same as mine and their drop downs behave as expected.

My last issue is that when I select the drop down "practice" I have the text set to turn black on mouse over, but because it's a nav-pill the background is white when it's selected/open. So if you have the menu open and you move your mouse away the text is white and the background is also white. Is there a CSS solution for this?

You can see the code in action here: http://www.bootply.com/5q1qGfp2c3

If you go to mobile view and scrunch the window down you can see what I mean about the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing the odd behavior because you're using [nav-pills](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills) instead of the default [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) elements. See working example with some ways to customize everything.

```css
/***Navbar Background Color, Border Removed ,Border Radius Sqaure***/

.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background: black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4f3838;
  border-radius: 0;
}
/***Link Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 3px 0 3px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
/***Link Color Hover Statr***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
}
/***Link Color Hover Statr***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:focus {
  background: white;
}
/***Link Background and Color Active State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
/***Navbar Brand Link Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}
/***Dropdown-menu Background Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
  background: black;
  border: none;
}
/***Dropdown-menu Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
/***Dropdown-menu Color Hover and Focus State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
/***Dropdown Background Active State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar.navbar-custom .nav li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar.navbar-custom .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
/***Toggle Button***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
}
/***Toggle Button Hover and Focus State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background: white;
  border: none;
}
/***Collapse Borders***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
  /***Dropdown-menu Color Hover and Focus State***/
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: black;
    background: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">D</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah, that fixes some issues, but causes a few others. Thanks for taking the time to do all that!

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109704/makes-nav-pills-collapsable-just-like-nav-bar-in-bootstrap which actually addresses the issue with the dropdown menu, but I'm having trouble making it work for mine.

Comment: What's it causing and just out of curiosity, whats the use case for the nav-pills that the default classes can't accomplish?

Comment: It's purely ascetic. The navbar-nav doesn't look as nice on the site I'm building as nav-pills. One thing I'm going for is using bootstrap, but making it slightly less cookie cutter. Your fix does take care of the issues I mentioned, but would involve a lot of tweaking to get it back to what I have now and would more than double the amount of code. Though, if I can't figure out a solution I might have to try it. But I imagine there must be a relatively straightforward fix.

Comment: If possible, post a jsfiddle or a link to what you have design wise (even if the functionality isn't working) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The answer is probably javascript. I'm just still such a beginner at it that I avoid it as much as possible. But adding the nav-stacked class worked. Now I just have to stop the overflow: scroll.

Comment: This might help https://jsfiddle.net/elektriheart/uq5502xg/ (This only adds (nets) 8 lines of CSS when accounting for the removal of the jQuery). As far as the issue with your overflow, it's not really an area for JS, because you're using a dropdown (if you change the background color of the dropdown-menu, you'll see what I'm saying) menu not intended for use in a mobile nav (per Bootstraps structure) you'd have to enhance your CSS to basically mimic the way the default nav operates.

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Add script links to the latest Bootstrap and jQuery JavaScript.  This should fix your mobile width navbar drop-down.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought. The first thing I did was make sure these links were up to date. I even copied and pasted what you put here in the hopes that I made a typo, but no luck.