# Make collapsible navigation Menu responsive with Bootstrap nav-Pills

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am new to webApps and I am trying to build a portfolio page with the help of Bootstrap. 
 The problem is if I use nav-bar-nav class in collapsible navigation, my web page looks perfactly responsive.

But if I change [nav-bar-nav](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_comp_nav-tabs&stacked=h) with Bootstrap [nav-pills](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_comp_nav-pills&stacked=h), I am unable to see my collapsible Menu button. Please see pic below for reference :-

[image]

I have learned collapsible Menu from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h) and I was trying to merge this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109704/makes-nav-pills-collapsable-just-like-nav-bar-in-bootstrap).

You can see what I have tried so far in Code Pan Here :- http://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/PNBarB

My HTML

```
<nav class="navbar nav-right">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button"  class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                  
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills head-menu" style ="float:right">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
  background-color :#722872;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  background-color :#722872;
 }
```

Please help me to point out what I am doing wrong, I have no prior experience in web UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Got it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
body {
    background-color: linen;
}

.nav {
  background-color :#722872;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  background-color :#722872;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Updated Code pan](http://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/PNBarB?editors=1000) in case anybody want to do the same.